# Pass variable from shell script to config file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to write a shell script to install multiple services dynamically. I don´t know too much about shell scripting or the unix shell general, so I really need some help. This is my shell file.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Ask the user for their name
echo What is the name of your domain?
read varname

echo You passed the domain name to your domain $varname successfully
```

This is my nginx.conf file.

```
server {
  listen                80;
  server_name           $varname;
  rewrite     ^(.*)     https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}
```

I want to pass `varname` to the nginx.conf file to set the server name based on the users input. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the file `nginx.conf` from a heredoc.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Ask the user for their name
echo What is the name of your domain?
read varname

cat > nginx.conf <<EOF
server {
  listen                80;
  server_name           $varname;
  rewrite     ^(.*)     https://\$server_name\$1 permanent;
}
EOF

echo You passed the domain name to your domain $varname successfully
```

Note: In the `rewrite` line I escaped the `$` characters to get literal `$` in the output instead of shell variable expansion.

If I enter `foobar`, this results in a file `nginx.conf`like this:

```
server {
  listen                80;
  server_name           foobar;
  rewrite     ^(.*)     https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. This will change value on line which is starting from space and has `server_name`'s last field to provided value by user.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Ask the user for their name
echo What is the name of your domain?
read varname

awk -v var="$varname" '/^ +server_name/{$NF=var} 1' nginx.conf > temp && mv temp nginx.conf &&\
echo You passed the domain name to your domain $varname successfully
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `envsubst` for this.

Rename your `nginx.conf` to `nginx.conf.template` and change your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "What is the name of your domain? " varname

export varname
envsubst '$varname' < nginx.conf.template > nginx.conf

echo "You passed the domain name to your domain $varname successfully"
```